# Selenium Can't locate the element while trying to click

Tags: python, selenium

I was scraping fembed just as a personal project but I kept running into errors.For getting the streaming url I needed to click the get the request through selenium wire. So I was trying to click on the button on this [url](https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67). Whenever I try to click it says can't find element.

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Chrome Stuff
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#All the driver Stuff
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
# driver.get("https://youtube.com")
url = 'https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67'
driver.get(url)
# driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

# bs4
r = requests.get(url) # r variable has all the HTML code
htmlContent = r.content # r returns response so if we want the code we write r.content
# print(htmlContent)        # printing the code
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())    # to print html in tree structure

# Clicking...
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.click() 
parent = driver.window_handles[0]
chld = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(parent)
body.click()
parent = driver.window_handles[0]
chld = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(parent)
# play button click
# btnplay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='loading-container']")
# print(btnplay)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

try:
    element =   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'loading-container')))
    element.click()
    print(f'Element found: {element}')
except TimeoutException:
    print('could not find it.')
# btnplay.click()
# btnplaybs4 = soup.find("div", class_="loading-container")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url
        )
driver.quit()
driver.close()
```

The console-

```
main.py:32: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_tag_name is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name) instead
  body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
could not find it.
https://accounts.google.com/ListAccounts?gpsia=1&source=ChromiumBrowser&json=standard
https://fembed-hd.com/v/l364xun6eeqrx67
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/player/base.js?v=1595607720
https://fembed-hd.com/api/source/l364xun6eeqrx67
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/jquery/slim-3.2.min.js?c=US&t=470
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/userdata/376887/poster/l/36/l364xun6eeqrx67.png?v=1645401494
https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js
https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/56313682
https://thumb.fvs.io/asset/userdata/376887/poster/l/36/l364xun6eeqrx67.png?v=1645401494
https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/56313682/1
https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/advert.gif
https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/49788082?wmode=7&page-url=https%3A%2F%2Ffembed-hd.com%2Fv%2Fl364xun6eeqrx67&charset=utf-8&site-info=%7B%22owner%22%3A%22376887%22%7D&browser-info=pv%3A1%3Agdpr%3A14%3Avf%3A7oivoclvhnrnrlmt4hr%3Afp%3A2198%3Afu%3A0%3Aen%3Autf-8%3Ala%3Aen-US%3Av%3A760%3Acn%3A1%3Adp%3A0%3Als%3A1412482081836%3Ahid%3A689365585%3Az%3A0%3Ai%3A20220321121023%3Aet%3A1647864623%3Ac%3A1%3Arn%3A524109570%3Arqn%3A1%3Au%3A1647864623700425535%3Aw%3A772x451%3As%3A800x600x24%3Ask%3A1%3Ahdl%3A1%3Acpf%3A1%3Ans%3A1647864619770%3Ads%3A0%2C401%2C160%2C41%2C5%2C0%2C%2C615%2C1%2C%2C%2C%2C1309%3Awv%3A2%3Aco%3A0%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ast%3A1647864623%3At%3AVideo%20shingeki-no-kyojin-the-final-season-part-2-episode-71645401122.0.mp4&t=gdpr(14)aw(1)ti(2)
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/img/favicon.ico?v=1553817714
https://adoptexplorationanguish.com/c0/ec/e9/c0ece9150690e04c8083b2de90d71095.js
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/player/jwplayer.core.controls.html5.js
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/player/related.js
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/default/player/provider.cast.js
https://fembed-hd.com/asset/userdata/376887/player/18015_logo.png?v=1631969623
https://thumb.fvs.io/asset/userdata/376887/player/18015_logo.png?v=1631969623
https://eu.messenger-notify.digital/go/463726
https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1
https://fvs.io/redirector?token=bTdlZDlsOFdLVnY2Mzl5SkNCUTlWb2lPRzQxNk9IMzFZTFJjOE1GOG9SWW1iMFlFclVmd3p1RC9Ga1YxYSsvcWJocXZrOTBITDB3K0JtQ1ZkWG43VjVIY0xwcVplNWFHL01sRG1LVnA1eTRvZ0Njci9IOVR3akszd01tTS9OdlZCUktIN0l1UnpwSklxd3NaTUZOOEFGYStoWXN6QWJqYURiUT06bnpuWXN1em81b2R3M21RMXY1UnczQT097kVg
https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/sender/1.0/cast_framework.js
https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/clank/97/cast_sender.js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbb987410a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 62, in <module>
    driver.close()
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 938, in close
    self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 423, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 333, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 355, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 74, in request
    return self.request_encode_url(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 96, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/runner/justforfun/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=56815): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/42d4358cbbf4ecbbf8468b38e955ea83/window (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbb987410a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Don't know why there are error.

Comment: Are you sure you want to click on `body` element? maybe you want to click on a play button there?

Comment: I want to click on the play button but the play button only activates when I click on the ads which is in the body. After that I need to click on the play button. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Please answer me

Comment: I tried yesterday but couldn't do that. I will try more later when I will have time for that.

Comment: ok thanks for you help reply as soon as possible

Comment: I have answered your new question. Actually it's the same question as here. I hope it helps. If so - please accept my answer there.

Comment: OK you're awesome let me check it there thanks for replying quick.